# Afreechart: How to reflect the changes on one graph when another graph is touched

Tags: android, graph

Anyone please help me on this. 
I action to be done here is, when X axis ranges on graph 1(accuracy) is zoomed, the same ranges also be reflected on graph 2(latency).

In clear,
When we are zooming the ranges 2,4,6,8,10 will be changed to 1,2,3,4,5.
When this changes happen on graph 1, the same ranges should be displayed on graph 2 also.
How I can achieve this.

[image]

I have tried using following way:

1. Analysed the scenario to find the way to trigger event in 'Accuracy View' chart when we do some action in 'Latency View' chart (and vice versa).
2. Written a code to trigger an event using dispatchOnTouch function. Unfortunately, dispatchOnTouch is not executing the event.
3. Investigated the issue in dispatchOnTouch function and found that OnTouchEvent on ControllerView class is ignoring the new event.

Thanks in Adavance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using the same library as you (I use androidplot) but I achieve this by creating my own class which extends the plot class of the library and implements OnTouchListener. I also defined a slavePlot variable in my class. The 1st plot is the slave of the 2nd and vice versa. Then when an action is made on one plot, you can do the same on the other.

```
public class MyXYPlot extends XYPlot implements OnTouchListener {

private MyXYPlot slavePlot;

public MyXYPlot(Context context, AttributeSet attributes)
{
    super(context, attributes);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public void setSlavePlot(MyXYPlot theplot)
{
    this.slavePlot = theplot;
}

 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //start gesture

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //end zoom

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;
    } 
    return true;
}
}
```

Hope this help!